# WPF: Click on Usercontrols Background does not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, events, routes, mouseevent

I have a WPF usercontrol which -simplified- looks something like this:

```
<UserControl Name="NiceUserControl" MouseLeftButtonUp="NiceUserControl_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
        <Border>
           <A lot Of Different Stuff like Buttons and Other usercontrols>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Like this the event "MouseLeftButtonUp" from the Usercontrol fires when one of the Child-Elements from the UserControl is clicked, but not, when i click the (empty) background of my control. ["Professional" Demo:](http://postimg.org/image/iv23mryat/) Click on green elements fires, on red background does not :(

I also tried addingthis eventhandler, which, by its last parameter should ignore when an event is already handled:

```
        NiceUserControl.AddHandler(MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(NiceUserControl_MouseDown), true);
```

but this only helps for example a textbox on my usercontrol,- The background still doesnt fire. 
Not even with PreviewMouse-Events or MouseEvents from the contained grid.

NOTE: I want for example Buttons inside the Control to have an own click event, but i want them to also trigger the usercontrols click event.

Comment: You need to set `Background` on `UserControl`, `Grid` or `Border` to something other then default null, like `Transparent` for example. Otherwise it's not hit test visible.

Comment: @dkozl its aktually as simple as this. i didn't event think about that. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably because you don't have the background property set.

Comment: Man, awesome! Thank you! its as simple as that -__- at least i now know how routed events work :D

Comment: Of Course! Stackoverflow said, i have to wait a few minutes to mark it ;)